# Scala with spark - "javax.servlet.ServletRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have simple scala application with spark dependencies. I am just trying to create spark context using the follwing code.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var sparkConfig : SparkConf  = new SparkConf() ;
    sparkConfig.setAppName("ProxySQL").setMaster("local");
    var sc = new SparkContext(sparkConfig) 

     }
```

When i try to run this code inside main - it throws security execption at new SparkContext(sparkConfig) with the following message .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.ServletRegistration"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package .
```

At problem tab of Eclipse, it shows one warning 
Description Path    Resource    Location    Type

```
More than one scala library found in the build path (D:/workspaces/scala/scalaEclipse/eclipse/plugins/org.scala-ide.scala210.jars_4.0.0.201503031935/target/jars/scala-library.jar, C:/Users/prems.bist/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar).This is not an optimal configuration, try to limit to one Scala library in the build path.     SQLWrapper  Unknown Scala Classpath Problem
```

I have scala installation of 2.10.4 at windows machine. 
Scala compiler version set at eclipse is 2.10.5 . What is causing this security exception? Is this the incompatiblity version issues or what exaclty else? How would i solve it?

Comment: How did you run your program? run directly in eclipse?

Comment: Yes.. It is an eclipse Scala IDE.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was more or less related with conflicting dependencies.

The following task resolve my issue.

> Go to Project
>
> Build Path -> Order and Export tab -> Change the order of
> javax.servlet jar
> either to bottom or top.

This Resolved the problem.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue while running a Spark Scala program. However, in my case there is no javax.servlet.jar. The only entries that I have in Project>>Build Path>> Order and Export tab are `MyApp/src/main/scala MyApp/src/main/resources MyApp/src/test/java MyApp/src/test/resources Scala Library container [2.10.6] JRE System Library [jre1.8.0_65]  Maven Dependencies`

Answer (score 2):

Well,as I follow the suggestion:Go to Project Build Path -> Order and Export tab -> Change the order of javax.servlet jar either to bottom or top.

I find my buidpath libiaries was changed and it seems mussy(too many small libs),maybe this was caused by maven.

So I try to remove all of them and reimport the libs and chose Project -> Maven ->Update Project !

Now ,it goes well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The name of your object with the main method shoul be the same as the setAppName("ProxySQL"), also you can exttend it with app and do not use main method, but this is only if you want I find it easy.

```
    package spark.sample

    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }

    /**
     * Created by anquegi on 18/05/15.
     */
    object ProxySQL {

      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        var sparkConfig: SparkConf = new SparkConf();

        sparkConfig.setAppName("ProxySQL").setMaster("local");

        var sc = new SparkContext(sparkConfig)

      }

    }
```

I normally use and object like for using Spark

```
package spark.sample

import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }

/**
 * Created by anquegi on 18/05/15.
 */
object ProxySQL extends App {

  val sparkConfig: SparkConf = new SparkConf();

  sparkConfig.setAppName("ProxySQL").setMaster("local[4]");

  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConfig)

}
```

I prefer to use val instead of var

You can also setMaster with `.setMaster("local[4]")`, and not work only with one

Comment: How does the name of object  is dependent on your app name. That won;t help me.

Answer (score 0):

It means you did not exclude the Servlet APIs from some dependency in your app, and one of them is bringing it in every time. Look at the dependency tree and exclude whatever brings in javax.servlet.

It should be already available in Spark, and the particular javax.servlet JAR from Oracle has signing info that you have to strip out, or simply exclude the whole thing.
some of the libraries were mention [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201502.mbox/%3CCAMAsSdJKmC8nWAtgTZKg_MpCYUW5_49RzPvqiRWBjwNVfC6s0g@mail.gmail.com%3E)